# Proving a map is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group; for $g\in G$ define $T_g:G\to G$ by $xT_g = g^{-1}xg$ for all $x\in G.$ Prove that $T_g$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Since $T_g$ is onto then for $y\in G$ let $x = gxg^{-1}$ then $xT_g = g^{-1}(x)g = g^{-1}(gyg^{-1})g = y$. Also, one to one is easy to see but how can I show $T_g$ is a homomorphism? If I have $x,y\in G$ then $(xy)T_g = g^{-1}(xy)g \ = \ ... \ = (xT_g)(yT_g)$.

How can I complete the $... \ $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(xT_g)(yT_g) = \Big(g^{-1} x g\Big)\Big(g^{-1} y g\Big) = g^{-1} x g g^{-1} y g = ... ?$$

Comment: Why are we allowed to put a $gg^{-1}$ in the middle of $g^{-1}(xy)g$?

Comment: @user104235 I just wrote the definition of $xT_g$ and $yT_g$, and erased some parentheses (using associativity, this is possible).

Comment: Alternatively, we are allowed to do that because $gg^{-1}=1$. So we can put $gg^{-1}$ wherever we please.

Comment: Oh you went backwards. How can I show it going my way?

Comment: @TBrendle Oh okay, so I cant stick that in the middle and I am done?

Comment: @user104235 Continue this until you get $(xy) T_g$, and then write everything backwards.